# How to add numbers and display them to the console in a bootloader?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-16, bootloader

I'm creating bootloader that should plus 512 to variable and print result until reaching the specified number. For me, it is 4194304, but the problem is that I really don't understand how to plus these numbers, because at the end I always get nothing or corrupted string. So how should I plus numbers correct?

```
cpu 386
bits 16
org 0h

start:
    cld
    xor ax,ax
    mov ss,ax
    mov sp,7c00h           ; setup stack

    mov ax,8000h
    mov es,ax              ; initialize es w/ 8000h
    mov ds,ax              ; initialize ds w/ 8000h

;===============================================================================================================

load_prog:
    mov ax,0206h           ;function/# of sec to read
    mov cx,0001h           ;0-5 sec # (counts from one), 6-7 hi cyl bits

    mov dh,00h             ;dh=head dl=drive (bit 7=hdd)
    mov bx,0h              ;data buffer, points to es:0
    int 13h
    cmp ah,0
    jne load_prog          ;this is allowable because it is relative

;============================================================================================================    

next:
    mov eax, [NUMBERS]
    add eax, 512           ;I think this have to plus numbers, so result have to be 512 = 0 + 512
    mov [NUMBERS], eax     ;And this i think have to store result to NUMBERS


print_1:
    mov si, msg0
    push ax
    cld
printchar_1:
    mov al,[si]
    cmp al,0
    jz print_2
    mov ah,0x0e
    int 0x10
    inc si
    jmp printchar_1


print_2:
    mov si, [NUMBERS]
    push ax
    cld
printchar_2:
    mov al,[si]
    cmp al,0
    jz print_3
    mov ah,0x0e
    int 0x10
    inc si
    jmp printchar_2


print_3:
    mov si, msg1
    push ax
    cld
printchar_3:
    mov al,[si]
    cmp al,0
    jz next
    mov ah,0x0e
    int 0x10
    inc si
    jmp printchar_3


done:
    hlt
    jmp done

;=====================================================================================================================    

MBR_Signature:
    msg0 db 'Counted numbers ',0
    msg1 db ' of 4194304',13,10,0
    NUMBERS dd 0
    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    db 55h,0aah
    times 4096-($-$$) db 0
```

Comment: You have to specify the operand-size for instructions with no register operands, otherwise it's ambiguous.  Like `cmp dword [NUMBERS], 4194304`.  Of course `NUMBERS` should be `dd 0` because you're using accessing it with dword (4-byte) operand-size.

Comment: Are you using an ancient version of NASM, or is this not a [mcve] of the error message?  Trying to assemble it gives the expected `error: operation size not specified`, not the `invalid combination of opcode and operands` you claim you get.

Comment: I've reopened this since the OP has modified the question so it assembles and it really is back to the question about why the code doesn't appear to be working. Although thr comparison is gone his question asks about why garbage or nothing is printed.

Comment: Yup, that's reasonable, we didn't need another duplicate of the ambiguous operand-size questions.  Now they removed the `cmp` so it's an infinite loop?  (And chose not to use `add dword [NUMBERS], 512`).  It should probably now be closed as lacking a [mcve] of what does happen.  The adding is fine, presumably whatever they're doing with BIOS interrupts isn't printing what they want, which is unsurprising using the same loop on a binary integer as on a string of ASCII characters.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Right, the loops are fine *if* `SI` is pointing at a string (which they are for the 1st and 3rd, but not the 2nd).  But I just noticed that this uses `mov si, [NUMBERS]` not `mov si, NUMBERS`, so it's using `[NUMBERS]` as a 16-bit pointer relative to DS, and dumping a string from every 512-byte offset.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Yes, I think they want to print a counter.  But they're not even printing the counter at all, they're using it as a pointer.  So that's kind of 2 separate bugs.  Anyway, there are duplicates for printing 32-bit integers using `div` by 10 to get the digits (in reverse order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** : It appears your main problem is that storing a number to memory using `MOV` instruction doesn't convert the value to a string. You must write the code to convert integers to strings.

---

You can use repeated division to convert a value in a register (EAX) to a different base (Base 10 for decimal digits). The general algorithm is

> ```
> val = number to convert
> repeat 
>   digit = val MOD 10     ; digit = remainder of val/10
>   val   = val DIV 10     ; val = quotient of val/10 
>   digit = digit + '0'    ; Convert digit to character value by adding '0'
>   Store digit
> until val == 0
> ```

If you have the number 1234:

- 1234/10=123 remainder 4 (digit)
- 123/10=12 remainder 3 (digit)
- 12/10=1 remainder 2 (digit)
- 1/10=0 remainder 1 (digit)
- Done

You'll observe that as we repeatedly divide by 10 we get the digits 4,3,2,1 which is reverse of what we want which is 1,2,3,4. You can come up with a mechanism to deal with reversing the string. One quick and dirty way is to push the digit on the stack in the reversed order and then you can pop each one back off the stack in the correct order. You could store each digit in a buffer in reverse order.

Since you are trying to display 32-bit unsigned numbers you will need to division with `val` in EAX. 64-bit division is done with value in EDX:EAX (where EDX is set to 0) by 10. The x86 instruction [`DIV`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/div) computes quotient (returned in EAX) and remainder (returned in EDX).

I recommend moving commonly used code into functions to reduce repetition, simplify development, and make the code easier to maintain

Create a function `uint32_to_str` that uses repeated division by 10 storing the ASCII digits on the stack as they are computed. At the end the ASCII digits are popped of the stack and stored into a buffer passed to the function. This works similar to the `itoa` function in that the number is always written at the start of the buffer. When finished the buffer is NUL(0) terminated. The function prototype could look like:

```
; uint32_to_str
;
; Parameters:
;     EAX   = 32-bit unsigned value to print
;     ES:DI = buffer to store NUL terminated ASCII string
;
; Returns:
;     None
;
; Clobbered:
;     None
```

Your code also prints strings.  create a `print_str` function with a prototype:

```
; print_str
;
; Parameters:
;     DS:SI = NUL terminated ASCII string to print
;
; Returns:
;     None
;
; Clobbered:
;     None
```

These are just example prototypes. You can choose to pass value and addresses in whichever registers you choose. You can also decide if your functions return a value and which registers are clobbered. In this code I preserve all the registers that are used. You can choose to preserve some or all of them, that is up to you.

Your bootloader could then look something like:

```
cpu 386
bits 16
org 0h

start:
    cld
    xor ax,ax
    mov ss,ax
    mov sp,7c00h               ; setup stack

    mov ax,8000h
    mov es,ax                  ; initialize es w/ 8000h
    mov ds,ax                  ; initialize ds w/ 8000h

;=================================================================================

load_prog:
    mov ax,0206h               ; function/# of sec to read
    mov cx,0001h               ; 0-5 sec # (counts from one), 6-7 hi cyl bits

    mov dh,00h                 ; dh=head dl=drive (bit 7=hdd)
    mov bx,0h                  ; data buffer, points to es:0
    int 13h
    cmp ah,0
    jne load_prog              ; this is allowable because it is relative

;=================================================================================

    mov eax, [NUMBERS]
next:
    add eax, 512               ; Advance value by 512

    mov si, msg0
    call print_str

    mov di, strbuf             ; ES:DI points to string buffer to store to
    call uint32_to_str         ; Convert 32-bit unsigned value in EAX to ASCII string

    mov si, di                 ; DS:SI points to string buffer to print
    call print_str

    mov si, msg1
    call print_str

    cmp eax, 1024*4096         ; End loop at 4194304 (1024*4096)
    jl next                    ; Continue until we reach limit

    mov [NUMBERS], eax         ; Store final value in NUMBERS

done:
    hlt
    jmp done


; print_str
;
; Parameters:
;     DS:SI = NUL terminated ASCII string to print
;
; Returns:
;     None
;
; Clobbered:
;     None

print_str:
    push ax
    push di

    mov ah,0x0e
.getchar:
    lodsb                      ; Same as mov al,[si] and inc si
    test al, al                ; Same as cmp al,0
    jz .end
    int 0x10
    jmp .getchar
.end:

    pop di
    pop ax
    ret

; uint32_to_str
;
; Parameters:
;     EAX   = 32-bit unsigned value to print
;     ES:DI = buffer to store NUL terminated ASCII string
;
; Returns:
;     None
;
; Clobbered:
;     None

uint32_to_str:
    push edx
    push eax
    push ecx
    push bx
    push di

    xor bx, bx                 ; Digit count
    mov ecx, 10                ; Divisor

.digloop:
    xor edx, edx               ; Division will use 64-bit dividend in EDX:EAX
    div ecx                    ; Divide EDX:EAX by 10
                               ;     EAX=Quotient
                               ;     EDX=Remainder(the current digit)
    add dl, '0'                ; Convert digit to ASCII
    push dx                    ; Push on stack so digits can be popped off in
                               ;     reverse order when finished

    inc bx                     ; Digit count += 1
    test eax, eax
    jnz .digloop               ; If dividend is zero then we are finished
                               ;     converting the number

    ; Get digits from stack in reverse order we pushed them
.popdigloop:
    pop ax
    stosb                      ; Same as mov [ES:DI], al and inc di
    dec bx
    jne .popdigloop            ; Loop until all digits have been popped

    mov al, 0
    stosb                      ; NUL terminate string
                               ; Same as mov [ES:DI], al and inc di

    pop di
    pop bx
    pop ecx
    pop eax
    pop edx
    ret
    ;================================================================================

    NUMBERS dd 0
    msg0    db 'Counted numbers ',0
    msg1    db ' of 4194304',13,10,0

    ; String buffer to hold ASCII string of 32-bit unsigned number
    strbuf times 11 db 0

    times 510-($-$$) db 0
MBR_Signature:
    db 55h,0aah
    times 4096-($-$$) db 0
```

---

### Alternative Versions of the Functions

I would generally use code that jumps into the middle of the loop to allow the exit condition (character being zero) to be done at the end rather than the middle. This avoids having to do the unconditional JMP instruction at the end:

```
; print_str
;
; Parameters:
;     DS:SI = NUL terminated ASCII string to print
;
; Returns:
;     None
;
; Clobbered:
;     None

print_str:
    push ax
    push di

    mov ah,0x0e
    jmp .getchar               ; Start by getting next character
.printchar:
    int 0x10
.getchar:
    lodsb                      ; Same as mov al,[si] and inc si
    test al, al                ; Is it NUL terminator?
    jnz .printchar             ; If not print character and repeat

    pop di
    pop ax
    ret
```

The original `uint32_to_str` was designed to always return the string starting at the beginning of the buffer passed. This is similar behaviour to *C*'s nonstandard function [`itoa`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/?kw=itoa) where the address of the buffer passed is the same address returned by the function.

One can dramatically simplify the code by removing the pushes and pops used to reverse the string. This can be done by writing the ASCII digits starting at a position in the output buffer where the NUL terminator will appear. The ASCII digits are inserted into the buffer from the end of the string towards the beginning as they are computed. The address returned from the function may be in the middle of the buffer passed. The start of the string of digits is returned back to the caller via the *DI* register in this code:

```
; uint32_to_str
;
; Parameters:
;     EAX   = 32-bit unsigned value to print.
;     ES:DI = buffer to store NUL terminated ASCII string.
;             buffer must be at a minimum 11 bytes in length to
;             hold the largest unsigned decimal number that
;             can be represented in 32-bits including a 
;             NUL terminator.
; Returns:
;     ES:DI   Points to beginning of buffer where the string starts.
;             This may not be the same address that was passed as a
;             parameter in DI initially. DI may point to a position in
;             in the middle of the buffer.
;
; Clobbered:
;     None

uint32_to_str:
    MAX_OUT_DIGITS equ 10      ; Largest unsigned int represented in 32-bits is 10 bytes

    push edx
    push eax
    push ecx

    mov ecx, 10                ; Divisor
    add di, MAX_OUT_DIGITS     ; Start at a point in the buffer we
                               ;     can move backwards from that can handle
                               ;     a 10 digit number and NUL terminator
    mov byte [es:di], 0        ; NUL terminate string

.digloop:
    xor edx, edx               ; Division will use 64-bit dividend in EDX:EAX
    div ecx                    ; Divide EDX:EAX by 10
                               ;     EAX=Quotient
                               ;     EDX=Remainder(the current digit)
    add dl, '0'                ; Convert digit to ASCII
    dec di                     ; Move to previous position in buffer
    mov [es:di], dl            ; Store the digit in the buffer

    test eax, eax
    jnz .digloop               ; If dividend is zero then we are finished
                               ;     converting the number

    pop ecx
    pop eax
    pop edx
    ret
```

---

**Footnotes**

- I'm unsure why you read the boot sector and extra sectors into memory at 0x0000:0x8000, but I have kept that code as is. That code works but I'm unsure why you are doing it.
- Since you used the directive `CPU 386` and were using 32-bit register *EAX* I created the code to use 32-bit registers when needed but used 16-bit registers otherwise. This cuts down on unnecessary instruction prefixes that bloat the code. This code will run in real-mode only on a system with a 386+ processor as a result. You can do 32-bit division using 16-bit registers but it is more complex and beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: I don't get the popularity of push/pop with 2 separate loops for itoa functions.  Just store and decrement a pointer, if you're already going to put it in a buffer and print from there instead of printing on the fly.  (Since you're about to just print, it's fine that the address of the first digit isn't known until after the end of the loop.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Because as it just so happens I wrote it this way originally to be more like traditional `itoa` that returns the same address as passed in (the assumption made is the characters should start at the beginning). However, the reason I  didn't respond right away is because I was cleaning up a version of the code that actually starts at the end of the buffer and moves back and returns the start in DI which I believe is what you are suggesting. The addendum does that with a slight mod to print_str as well.

Comment: In SO answers I've written, I tend to inline the printing right after the digit-loop ([How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](//stackoverflow.com/a/46301894)) because they're both small and still separable without formally calling one a "return value".  But yeah, you can do that, like glibc's internal-use [`char *_itoa(uint64_t value, char *buflim, base, upper_case)`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/generic/_itoa.h.html#39) function (I compacted the types) that takes a pointer to `buffer + size`.

Comment: @PeterCordes : I tend to not inline if I believe that there is a functional use for separate functions.  In this case I'd rather the two functions stand alone so that you can use uint32_to_str whether you intend to print out not. Also means that if you choose to write directly to the screen (at 0xb800:0x0000) you don't need to amend a conversion function. My opinion is the separate functions are more practical.

Comment: My experience with asm has only ever been for performance optimization, where not manually inlining would defeat the purpose of writing in asm instead of letting a compiler do it.  So that's always my instinct.  If I did want to write directly to screen, I'd store to it inside the digit loop!  (Or copying in dword chunks for efficiency is prob. better on modern CPUs if the VRAM is UC instead of WC.)   Anyway, regardless, after having used the `*p-- = digit;` trick, it's my go-to first option for any digit_loop.

Comment: If a block of code is basically separate and can be replaced or copy/pasted to another project without modifying the part before, it doesn't matter a huge amount whether it's a separate function that's `call`ed or not, does it?  So if you wanted to change printing, you'd just have to modify the printing part of a convert + print function if those are still 2 separate loops.

Comment: That's fine for academia, but if you are writing code that actually be useful (like a library of bootloader functions that may be run outside of a high level language) that may be used in a variety of ways then I have a preference for this. I do not believe there is great utility in a function that forces you to print when you do a conversion. In the real world when you are writing potential routines that could be put in a library or reused how many implementations have a `itoa_and_print`? Not many I suppose. You will not convince me that creating a specific function here is justifiable.

Comment: Sort of like someone asking on SO how to print the number 100 to the screen (there was such a question previously) I could have gone for the very impractical.but still correct  _write the number 1 0 0_ directly to the console. Would be the shortest solution but not very useful if you want to print the number 200 ;-). Doing no conversion would be the most performant solution.

Comment: That's true.  But if your only caller in a small example does want to print, I figure why not simplify.  You can easily turn the two loops into separate functions anyway once you do want conversion into a buffer, because they're already separable.  (This is the key point; unlike the hard-coded "100" case, the pieces are still there and easy to turn into separate function).  And then you'll have to see if conversion into the *end* of a buffer is useful for you or not, or if *that* has to be modified, too.

Comment: Your way has the advantage of demonstrating this software engineering principle for beginners.  My way is mostly justified by the fact that *I* think it's easy to separate into separate functions if/when needed, but maybe some readers miss that and could have benefited from learning that lesson about identifying cleanly-separable pieces.

Comment: @PeterCordes No, my way also has value especially in bootloaders where putting these kind of function in include files is very common place. If you review many of the bootloader/OSDev questions that show up they usually rely on small libraries of useful functions that may be used in a variety of ways. Your way ties two functions together that may have very little utility if you are looking to do a conversion but don't intend or want to write to the console.