# How binary to decimal conversion is implemented in c language

Tags: c, programming-languages, implementation

How do implementations of `printf` efficiently implement conversion of integer values to decimal?

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve].  Your question seems out of scope for Stack Overflow.  2's complement is not the only binary representation supported by C.  Read the language and standard library standards documents (do a search).

Comment: @jwdonahue: (a) An MRE is not needed here. This question is not a request for debugging help. (b) The language and standard library documents do not provide information on how the conversions are implemented, which is what the question requests.

Comment: Actually, the standard uses wording of the form "undefined" and "implementation defined" or some such.  I always check whether a new user has read [ask] and if not, then I suggest that and [mcve] for their own edification.

Comment: `any official c documentation that supports your answers` it is implemented in the standard library, which is implemented for your target and compiler. Standard does not care how it is implemented.

Comment: `As far as I know, integers are kept in memory by 2's complement method` they can be. But they do not have to. Standard doesn't care about it

Comment: `When we call printf or any other stdout method` C doesn't know anything about *methods*.

Comment: @P__J__: So what if the C standard does not say how it is implemented. How it is implemented is an interesting question, regardless of what the standard says. Any novice can write a routine that gets the job done, but, as the question mentions, implementations should be really efficient. That is a harder question to answer, and it is one that deserves to be asked and answered. The votes down are inappropriate; this is a worthwhile question that just needs some editing.

Comment: In this answer I provide an algorithm (pseudo code) and an assembly solution (not C) for the unsigned integer case (repeated division): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56480273/how-to-add-numbers-and-display-them-to-the-console-in-a-bootloader/56483319#56483319 . To do signed numbers you have to check if the value is negative. If it is you negate it and make it positive then use the same procedure for unsigned integers and then you add a minus symbol in front when finished.

Comment: It looks like the GNU libc implementation of the binary-to-decimal conversion, or part of it, is in `stdio-common/_itoa.c` of the [source packages here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/), such as [this glibc.230.tar.gz one](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.30.tar.gz).

Comment: "How binary to decimal conversion is implemented in c language" has one **gotcha** - STL cheats.  An standard library implementation can use _undefined behavior_ and _implementation defined behavior_ to its advantage - it can "know" how UB and IDB work - for that system..  Portable user code should not.  E.g. Some standard library source do `int i; ..... unsigned u = ... (unsigned)-i;`  (UB with `i==INT_MIN`).  So seeing STL source is not always good practice for user code.

Answer (score 1):

On modern computers, computing is generally much faster than I/O, and such is the case here. The C library is going to use a straightforward approach. The modulo option is used to get the least significant digit, and divide is used to consume the digit and iterate. Unfortunately, the digits are generated in reverse order relative to I/O order, so they need to be buffered before they're output. This could be done with recursion, but the maximum number of digits is known a priori, so it is faster to preallocate a character array.

The number may be negative, so that is handled outside the loop.

```
char digits[N];
p = &digits[N-1];
*p-- = 0;
unsigned x = integer_input;
if (integer_input < 0 && integer_input >= -INT_MAX) x = -integer_input;
do {
    *p-- = (x % 10) + '0';
    x /= 10;
} while x != 0;
if (integer_input < 0) *p-- = '-'
// now p points to c string
```

This is [how newlib does it](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=blob;f=newlib/libc/stdlib/utoa.c;h=5ef304ce49bfa826c206e37aa5c874f6cedb1de5;hb=HEAD), though it supports bases other than 10.

This is [how glibc does it](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/_itoa.c#L163-L189).

Both follow the approach above, though generalized.

Comment: This is a way to do it. What makes you think it is the way that is used in standard C libraries? Shouldn’t they use some more efficient method?

Comment: The question is "how is it implemented?" not "what does the standard mandate?" This is the method used in a few stdlibs I've seen.

Comment: I did not ask what the standard mandates. I asked what makes you think this is how C implementations do it. It is crude and inefficient, so I do not expect it is what any quality C implementation would actually use. This answer asserts “The C library is going to use a straightforward approach.” I believe that is false for good implementations.

Comment: Added a link to newlib

Comment: It also has a bug in it, as the smallest 2's complement negative integer (INT_MIN) is not handled correctly.

Comment: The code in the GNU C Library, which I linked to above, certainly is not straightforward, so this answer is incorrect in that regard.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, I addressed your concern, but now the solution assumes 2's complement.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I meant straightforward in the sense that just divide and modulo operations are used (in my code, in newlib, and in glibc) as opposed to some tricky bit twiddling or multiply by reciprocal of 10 or something extraordinary,

Comment: To avoid `assumes 2's complement`, code could use `integer_input != INT_MIN` --> `integer_input >= -INT_MAX`.

Comment: The `x < 0` was leftover from an earlier edit; it's superfluous and I meant to delete it. It's gone now.

Comment: Thanks, @chux-ReinstateMonica, I've used your `integer_input >= -INT_MAX` suggestion; very helpful.